# Push code to GitLab except package-lock.json

Tags: git, gitlab, package-lock.json

I am working with a React project and I am going to deploy my app to Vercel, but when I push my code to GitLab I don't want to push `package-lock.json` because it will get error with Vercel. Does anyone know the fastest way to push code to GitLab except `package-lock.json` using command line?

Comment: It might be better to ask about fixing the error with Vercel, because without the lockfile your build isn't reproducible and you may end up with other, harder-to-debug problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `package-lock.json` to your `.gitignore` file. If it was previously added and committed to git, you should also remove it from there: `git rm --cached package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the `package-lock.json` file and push the code to gitlab beacuse whenever you do the `npm i` again, this `package-lock.json` will be created again. Like

- rm package-lock.json
- git add .
- git commit -m "your message"
- git push origin your_branch_name

Or you can `checkout` the file after `git add` like

- git add .
- git checkout `package-lock.json`
- git commit -m "your message"
- git push origin your_branch_name

By the way you should try adding the `package-lock.json` into `.gitignore` file if you don't want to do the same steps again in your future deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a .gitignore file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).